# How to enable transmission-daemon start at startup?

Tags: raspbmc

I have transmission-daemon installed and running. I have to go and start it manually after each restart, though. I have been reading up on upstart and such, but still am not able to get transmission-daemon to start at boot time automatically. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Raspbmc is based on Raspbian. By running `sudo apt-get install transmission-daemon`, a start script should be installed in `/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon`. Can you see it?

Answer (score 8):

If everything is installed correctly, you should just type:

```
sudo update-rc.d transmission-daemon defaults
```

Comment: I have used this, however it starts but with some kind of problem since it shows the UI but an error pop up. I always have to restart the service for working.

Comment: same here... I'll update if I'll find a solution

Answer (score 1):

Even if you have transmission installed, you still might not have transmission-daemon installed. So you might need to run

```
sudo apt-get install transmission-daemon
```

before running

```
sudo update-rc.d transmission-daemon defaults
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution to this myself, and finally found it elsewhere. The problem is not with raspbian, it's in the interaction between transmission ans systemd. The latter considers the network to be up, and tells transmission-daemon to start. Transmission cannot start the RPC listener for the web ui, because the network is not properly up yet, by its definition of "up".

Transmission 2.90 fixes this by retrying to create the RPC listener. Raspbian stretch now contains Transmission 2.92, and with that, everything just works, with no manual interaction required. So if you're still on jessie, consider upgrading (either your entire system, or just the transmission packages).