# Openelec, transmission-demon not starting on boot

Tags: kodi, openelec

I installed the package via the unofficial repo on openelec 4.0.1. I can start transmission via the shell, but it will not start by itself during boot.

What should I do?

Another thing I perceived is, that if I start ~/.xbmc/addons/service.downloadmanager.transmission/bin/transmission.start, everything is ok, and I can access the ui; but when I run ~/.xbmc/addons/service.downloadmanager.transmission/bin/transmission-demon, my client's ip is not allowed to access the web ui, as if it would use a different config.

Attention: this is no duplicate for [How to enable transmission-daemon start at startup?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3380/how-to-enable-transmission-daemon-start-at-startup). Openelec is not debian based and there is neither apt nor /etc/init.d.

I also asked this questions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23712098/openelec-transmission-demon-not-starting-on-boot, but It seems a bit out of place (even though the are quite a bit of other raspi related questions there).

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: Well, I stopped using transmission on the raspi alltogether. I wass getting bad writes and overall it was too taxing. Raspi IO still sucks.